# Fertility Boost/Monsoon Abilities

Tags: reus

For example I have a level 1 Fruit Plant Ability and used a L2/3 Fertility/Monsoon on that tile and then used a level 1 Fruit Aspect Ability.

The question is: *Is there a chance that the Fertility/Monsoon Ability can make the buffed plant with a Greater/Sublime Aspect on it?*

Comment: I have never gotten a Greater or Sublime aspect using a Level 1 aspect, regardless of how high my Fertility/Monsoon level is, and I always try to Fertility/Monsoon a square before placing an aspect. But I suppose I could just have just been very unluckly.

Comment: it appears that you cannot stack these bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

No. The fertility boost increases the chance of Potent, Greater, and Sublime Aspects, but it does not grant the ability to reach those levels.

If you want Greater / Sublime Aspects, you must upgrade your Aspect Abilities.

Comment: How do you upgrade your aspect abilities?

Comment: @jaminja All of your abilities upgrade as you increase the number of ambassadors you have. If you hover over the Aspect in question (and are at least level ** or level ***), you should see a list of the required ambassadors.